# Convert date format using python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert the date format from a column in an specific format in python

**Input Data:**

```
    Date 

01/10/2020
01-mar-2020
1-june-2019
01/01/2021
1/11/2020
```

**Output looking for:**

```
    Date 

2020-10-01
2020-03-01
2019-06-01
2021-01-01
2020-11-01
```

Code been using so far:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

With the above script i am getting this output:

```
   Date
2020-01-10
2020-03-01
2019-06-01
2021-01-01
2020-01-11
```

but its not giving the output as what i am trying to find.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `dayfirst` parameter of `to_datetime()` method and set that equal to `True`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce',dayfirst=True)
```

Finally:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Now if you print `df` or `df['Date']` you will get your desired output:

```
0    2020-10-01
1    2020-03-01
2    2019-06-01
3    2021-01-01
4    2020-11-01
```